# Haskell - Find first 0 in a 2 level nested list

Tags: list, haskell

Imagine you have a 2 dimensional list of lists like this:
`[[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 3], [3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9], ....]`
I want to get the coordinate of the first `0` value of the `array -> (1, 7)`.

I have tried using `map` and `elemIndex`.

Comment: What have you tried with `map` and `elemIndex` and how did that not work the way you expected?

Comment: I had problems with Maybe Int. I used map to map all list to their first index of 0, but then I got 'Just x' and didn't know how to work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `elemIndex` and `map` are quite unnecessary to solve this problem. You simply need to keep track of a set of beginning coordinates and modify it as you recursively transverse the list of lists.

Clearly, the value we're looking for can never be in an empty list, so that case will return `Nothing`.

If the first list in the list is empty, it also can't be there, so we go to the next list, incrementing the first coordinate and resetting the second to `0`.

If that first list is not empty, we check to see if *its* first element is the one we're looking for. If it is, we can return the coordinates wrapped up with `Just`, and the recursion ends.

Otherwise, continue by incrementing the second coordinate and considering the remainder of the list of lists.

```
findCoords :: Eq a => (Int, Int) -> a -> [[a]] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findCoords _ _ [] = Nothing
findCoords (i, _) v ([]:xs) = findCoords (i+1, 0) v xs
findCoords (i, j) v ((x:y):xs) 
  | v == x = Just (i, j)
  | otherwise = findCoords (i, j+1) v (y:xs)
```

This requires manually passing `(0, 0)` when called. This can be cleaned up by using a local `aux` function.

```
findCoords :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findCoords = aux (0, 0)
  where
    aux _ _ [] = Nothing
    aux (i, _) v ([]:xs) = aux (i+1, 0) v xs
    aux (i, j) v ((x:y):xs) 
      | v == x = Just (i, j)
      | otherwise = aux (i, j+1) v (y:xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to do something to a number of items, the place to start is to work out how to do that something to just one item. Then map your function across all of the items.

Let's pick this list: `[3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9]`

The type of elemIndex can be seen in GHCi by using `:t`.

```
 :m Data.List      -- load module
 :t elemIndex      -- show type
```

This returns `elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`

So, we give it a value and a list and it returns the index as a Maybe.

```
 elemIndex 0 [3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9] -- returns Just 7
```

Perhaps we call this function `f`

```
 f = elemIndex 0
```

Then we map this function across the list of lists.

```
 result = map f lst
```

The biggest question is what you mean by the first value. If you have a list like `[[1,2,3,0],[0,1,2,3]]`, which is the first value? That will inform how you process the results of the map.

The way that you handle a `Maybe Int`, is at the simplest level to match against the two value `Just x` and `Nothing`.

```
f :: Maybe Int -> String
f (Just x) = show x
f Nothing = "Nothing"

main = do
  putStrLn $ f (Just 3)
  putStrLn $ f (Nothing)
```

Using these ideas I wrote this code, which appears to do what is required. Having mapped `elemIndex` over the lists, I find the first matching list using `findIndex`. The function `findIndex` takes a predicate for `Just x`, returning `True` if so, and `False` for `Nothing`. Then it's just a case of matching with `Just` and `Nothing` to extract the result.

```
import Data.List

lst=[[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 3], [3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9]]

f = elemIndex 0

pJust :: Maybe a  -> Bool
pJust (Just x)  = True
pJust Nothing = False

main = do

  let results = map f lst
  let location = findIndex pJust results

  case location of
    Just index -> do
       let location2 = results !! index
       case location2 of
           Just index2 -> putStrLn $ "(" ++ 
              show index ++ "," ++
              show index2 ++ ")"
           Nothing -> putStrLn "Search failed"
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Search failed"
```